# file handling on node js which is better FileReader or Buffer.from(arrayBuffer)

Tags: javascript, node.js, buffer, filereader, arraybuffer

```
which is more efficient  on nodejs server

1) 
let file :File = (await formData()).get('input-png')
let arrayBuffer = file.arrayBuffer()
buffer = Buffer.from(arrayBuffer)

2)
let file :File = (await formData()).get('input-png')
let reader = new FileReader(file)
reader.load = function (){
  const buffer = Buffer.from(reader.result)
}
```

ChatGPT

In a Node.js server environment, the second option would be more efficient for handling file uploads. Here's why:

Option 2:

The file is obtained from the formData using (await formData()).get('input-png'), assuming you are working with a multipart/form-data request.

1. A FileReader instance is created with the file object.
2. An onload event handler is attached to the reader to handle when the file is successfully loaded.
3. Within the onload handler, the reader.result contains the file content as an ArrayBuffer.
4. The Buffer.from(reader.result) is used to convert the ArrayBuffer to a Buffer object.

**This approach is more efficient because:**

1. It reads the file content directly as an ArrayBuffer using FileReader.
2. It avoids unnecessary intermediate steps like converting the File to an ArrayBuffer and then to a Buffer.
3. On the other hand, Option 1 involves an additional step of converting the File object to an ArrayBuffer before creating the Buffer object.

Therefore, in a Node.js server environment, Option 2 would generally be more efficient for handling file uploads using Buffer.from(reader.result) directly.

---

**is this correct??**

it seems that both approaches are the same....